# JQuery Drag and Drop Count Validation on Submit in Divs in a Table

Tags: html, validation, count, drag-and-drop, html-table

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simonekimber87/k6wsx2y6/)

I have a table that has divs, in those divs I have images that I would like to drag and drop from the first column into the next two columns. That bit has been done, but what I would like to happen is when the user clicks 'Finish' it runs a count validation to make sure the user has moved out all the images from the 1st column into the next two columns.

Can this be done?

```
<td><div class="options" id="option1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one of best way to check on drag and drop is to give parameter to `.options` which will change when the `.options` dropped. In my implementation, I use `JQuery.data()` to give parameter on `.options`, as you can see on here : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6wsx2y6/2/)

Comment: Awesome! So is it possible to add a 'None' equals greater than 0, then alert "Please go back and place all images in the columns"?

Comment: Also when recreating this outside of JSFiddle it doesn't work :/ Do I need to add something like this? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SimoneKimber It is possible, you just need to add a checking and alert the message. Yes, When creating JSFiddle you need to add script for JQuery and JQuery UI. You can find it here : [JQuery](http://jquery.com) and [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much I had a go at adding an alert to the finish button but I don't know where I am going wrong :( $(".finishButton").click(function() {
    var s = 0,
      w = 0,
      n = 0;
   if (n<=0) {
  alert('Well done, you have completed this activity, your results are: 'Strength:' + s + '\n' + 'Weakness:' + w + '\n' Please go back now and print the page for your future reference);
   }else {
  if (n>=0) {
  alert('Please go back and finish placing options in the strengths or weaknesses coloumns');

Comment: @SimoneKimber you missed some of the sign ' on your code. I have added the alert as you wish : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k6wsx2y6/3/)

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me so much!

Comment: @SimoneKimber glad I can help. you can tag this as answer. So the next reader will know. Thanks